# Probabilistics estimation and small numbers

Tags: math, probability

Suppose

```
 P(x|y)= 0.0005 and P(x)=0.0003 

p(y|x) = p(x|y) / p(x) (Bayes' theorem and ignoring p(y))
```

The results of p(y|x) =1.66 which is basically wrong given that probabilities can not be > 1

I would expect a really small number to be the result. What is the proper way of dealing with small probabilities.

Comment: Can you show us the `[java]` code you are having trouble with or does this not have anything to do with Java?

Comment: @PeterLawrey nothing to do with java. Added only in case there is any library to work with

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ - but really, there's little to add to what @PeterLawrey said.

Comment: @PeterLawrey nothing wrong with the input. Knowing that y happens might increase p(x|y) and make it bigger than p(x)

Comment: You are right, the answer is you can't ignore `P(y)`, it cannot be assumed to be 1 as you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't ignore P(y), it cannot be assumed to be 1 as you have here. P(y) must be between [0.0,  0.6]

Comment: Thanks. but I don't agree with this. P(y) can range from 0.0 to 1.0
The range you suggested make the results valid, I agree but doesn't seem to be mathematically correct.

Comment: @DotNet If P(y) = 1 then P(x|y) = P(x) as they must be the same thing or you have a contradiction.

Comment: thanks Peter. I agree but I'm ignoring it because I'm assuming it is fixed for all y's values. not because it is 1. p(y) is 0.0002

Comment: @DotNet if you use the original formula this make sense.

Comment: Thanks, i think you are right. P(y) can not be ignored.